# Understanding Validated.applicative in kotlin arrow library

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, arrow-kt

I come across below generic function which takes two `Either` type and a function as an argument. If both arguments are `Either.Right` then apply the function over it and returns the result, if any of the argument is `Either.Left` it returns NonEmptyList(Either.Left). Basically it performs the independent operation and accumulates the errors.

```
fun <T, E, A, B> constructFromParts(a: Either<E, A>, b: Either<E, B>, fn: (Tuple2<A, B>) -> T): Either<Nel<E>, T> {
    val va = Validated.fromEither(a).toValidatedNel()
    val vb = Validated.fromEither(b).toValidatedNel()
    return Validated.applicative<Nel<E>>(NonEmptyList.semigroup()).map(va, vb, fn).fix().toEither()
}

val error1:Either<String, Int> = "error 1".left()
val error2:Either<String, Int> = "error 2".left()

val valid:Either<Nel<String>, Int> = constructFromParts(
        error1,
        error2
){(a, b) -> a+b}

fun main() {
    when(valid){
        is Either.Right -> println(valid.b)
        is Either.Left -> println(valid.a.all)
    }
}
```

Above code prints

```
[error 1, error 2]
```

Inside the function, it converts Either to ValidatedNel type and accumulates both errors 
***( Invalid(e=NonEmptyList(all=[error 1])) Invalid(e=NonEmptyList(all=[error 2])) )***

My question is how it performs this operation or could anyone explain the below line from the code.

```
return Validated.applicative<Nel<E>>(NonEmptyList.semigroup()).map(va, vb, fn).fix().toEither()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's say I have a similar data type to `Validated` called `ValRes`

```
sealed class ValRes<out E, out A> {
    data class Valid<A>(val a: A) : ValRes<Nothing, A>()
    data class Invalid<E>(val e: E) : ValRes<E, Nothing>()
}
```

If I have two values of type `ValRes` and I want to combine them accumulating the errors I could write a function like this:

```
fun <E, A, B> tupled(
            a: ValRes<E, A>,
            b: ValRes<E, B>,
            combine: (E, E) -> E
        ): ValRes<E, Pair<A, B>> =
            if (a is Valid && b is Valid) valid(Pair(a.a, b.a))
            else if (a is Invalid && b is Invalid) invalid(combine(a.e, b.e))
            else if (a is Invalid) invalid(a.e)
            else if (b is Invalid) invalid(b.e)
            else throw IllegalStateException("This is impossible")
```

- if both values are `Valid` I build a pair of the two values
- if one of them is invalid, I get a new `Invalid` instance with the single value
- if both are invalid, I use the `combine` function to build `Invalid` instance containing both values.

Usage:

```
tupled(
    validateEmail("stojan"),    //invalid
    validateName(null)          //invalid
) { e1, e2 -> "$e1, $e2" }
```

This works in a generic way, independent of the types E, A and B. But it only works for two values. We could build such a function for N values of type `ValRes`.

Now back to arrow:

```
Validated.applicative<Nel<E>>(NonEmptyList.semigroup()).map(va, vb, fn).fix().toEither()
```

`tupled` is similar to `map` (with hardcoded success function). `va` and `vb` here are similar to `a` and `b` in my example. Instead of returning a pair of values, here we have a custom function (`fn`) that combines the two values in case of success.

Combining the errors:

```
interface Semigroup<A> {
  /**
   * Combine two [A] values.
   */
  fun A.combine(b: A): A
}
```

`Semigroup` in arrow is a way for combining two values from the same type in a single value of that same type. Similar to my `combine` function. `NonEmptyList.semigroup()` is the implementation of `Semigroup` for `NonEmptyList` that given two lists adds the elements together into a single `NonEmptyList`.

To sum up:

- If both values are `Valid` -> it will combine them using the supplied function
- If one value is `Valid` and one `Invalid` -> gives back the error
- If both values are `Invalid` -> Uses the `Semigroup` instance for `Nel` to combine the errors

Under the hood this scales for 2 up to X values (22 I believe).